# How to implement for loop in javacc

Tags: parsing, javacc, gw-basic

I am implementing a parser based on javacc which will be able to GW Basic programs.

I implemented for loop like this

```
void forloop(Token line):
{
    Token toV;
    Token toI;
    Token step;
    Token next;
    Token var;
}
{
    <FOR> var=<VARIABLE> "=" Expression() { instructions.add("STORE " + var.image); } <TO> toV=<INTEGER> <STEP> step=<INTEGER> 
    {   
        instructions.add("LABEL "+labelsCntr);
        instructions.add("LOAD "+var.image);
        instructions.add("CONST "+toV.image);
        instructions.add("SUB");
        instructions.add("CONST 0");

    }
    ( Line() )*
    next = <INTEGER> <NEXT> <VARIABLE>
    {
        instructions.add("LINE "+next.image);
        instructions.add("LOAD "+step.image);
        instructions.add("LOAD "+var.image);
        instructions.add("ADD");
        instructions.add("JMP LABEL "+(labelsCntr));

        labelsCntr++;

    }    
}
```

But it does not work.

How can I implement for loop so that it works.

Or where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things I don't see in your machine code that I would have expected. One is a conditional jump out of the loop. When the variable exceeds toV, control should jump to the first instruction after the loop.  Second I don't see where the var is changed. At the end of the loop you add the value of the variable to the step value, but you don't store the result back into the variable.

There are also a few checks I expect need to be done at compile time that are missing: That the variable in the NEXT statement matches that in the VAR and that the step is positive.

Comment: The step doesn't have to be positive. Something like `FOR N=10 TO 0 STEP -1` isn't just allowed but actually useful.  But there is much much more missing as `FOR` and `NEXT` don't have to form such a ”brace” like structure as in modern/structured languages where each `NEXT` belongs to exactly one, easy identifiable `FOR`. `FOR` needs to push state on a loop stack (position of loop body in code,variable name, end value, step) and `NEXT` needs to check that stack and act accordingly. The check for loop end is in `NEXT`. A loop is _always_ executed once.

Comment: Well fair.  I didn't really look up  the details of the language specification.  But I think I did answer the question of why the code didn't work.  I last used BASIC in a 1978.